# best way to include database in a wpf program?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, database

I am new to c# programming and WPF technology. I have an idea of developing an engineering program. my program needs lot of data to work, so I need to include a database with my app. I have written the logic part but at this step I don't know how to add my data to program. should I simply create arrays of them in a class? or there is a better way to do this?
I have heard about SQL, but I don't know how that relates to C# programming. also, I need my program to run on any PC without requiring the user to install any extra database program.

Comment: Chose embed DB (like SQL COmpact or SQLLite), then learn howto work with chosen DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into using [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/). You will also need the [System.Data.SQLite](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) ADO.NET provider to work with it within your WPF application.

And the provider is available via. NuGet:

https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki#q5

Answer (score 0):

If you need an embedded object database try LiteDB ([litedb.org](http://www.litedb.org))

So you use 100% C# managed code and need no knowledge about SQL. You just need to add the DLL to your program.